# Angular routing with multiple children

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have routing like this

```
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'component1',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'component1',
        component: Component1,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'administration',
            component: Component1Administration,
          },
          {
            path: 'management',
            component: Component1Management,
            children: [
              {
                path: ':id',
                component: Component1Management,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
```

When I have selected item i'm want to redirect to my component with given ID, i'm using this code
`this.router.navigate([selectedId], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute});`

But for some reason angular is trying to reach to this url (let's say 123 is ID)
`https://localhost:4200/component1/123` and it goes to home because given path doesn't exist, but it should go to `https://localhost:4200/component1/management/123`

I was trying to use different params in NaviationExtras but nothing helped

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem. Ideally in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).